# Олимпиадная задача на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Совсем недавно закончился межгалактический турнир по известной онлайн-игре «Defence of the Young». Во время турнира страсти разыгрались не на шутку, и судьи только и успевали, что планировать проведение матчей и следить за соблюдением правил. К несчастью, ни одна команда из галактики Млечный путь не смогла пройти отбор на соревнования, поэтому мы традиционно болели за наших друзей из скопления Андромеды.

Всего в соревнованиях участвовало n команд. Турнир проводился по олимпийской системе, то есть команда выбывала сразу после первого проигрыша. Поскольку на турнире присутствовали команды с самым разным уровнем мастерства, то сетка турнира могла быть совершенно произвольной. В частности, количество участвовавших команд совершенно не обязательно было равно какой-либо степени двойки. Также известно, что никакая команда не играла две игры в один день.

К сожалению, во время бурного чествования ставшей победителем команды «Kind Genius», были утеряны записи о самом турнире. Единственная информация, которую смогло найти жюри, это количество матчей, сыгранное в каждый из дней турнира. Жюри просит вас, пользуясь этими данными и информацией о структуре турнира из предыдущего абзаца, восстановить хотя бы значение n — количество команд, участвоваших в турнире.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных записано целое число k ( 1 ≤ k ≤ 100 000 ) –– количество дней, которое длился межгалактический турнир по DOTY. В следующей строке записаны k неотрицательных целых чисел, не превышающих 10 9 , i -е из них задаёт количество игр, сыгранных в i -й день турнира.

Выходные данные
Выведите единственное целое число n — количество команд, участвовавших в турнире. Гарантируется, что n может быть однозначно восстановлено по входным данным и будет не больше 10 9 . Также гарантируется, что в турнире участвовала хотя бы одна команда.

Примечание
Одной из возможных сеток турнира во втором примере является:

Первая и вторая команда играют матч в первый день.
Победитель первого матча играет с третьей командой во второй день.
Победитель второго матча играет в финале с четвёртой командой в третий день соревнований.
Примеры
входные данные
3
2 2 1
выходные данные
6
входные данные
5
0 1 0 1 1
выходные данные
4

Comment: Кто участвует в олимпиаде - мы или вы?

Comment: Благодарю за ваше замечание,ответ на ваш вопрос - я, но я столкнулся с проблемой в следствие чего прошу людей помочь.

Comment: Вы просите не помочь, а решить задачу вместо вас.

Comment: Именно это я и прошу, так как я хочу понять как подобные задания решать. Я прошу у Вас прощения за то, что смею просить Вас о таком. Но я честно очень хочу это решить, но у меня пока ничего не получается. :(

Comment: Что это за балет?

Comment: как мне ответить) Я просто не умею решать пока пободные задачи, а у меня сроки поджимают(

Comment: В той ветке дан же ответ

Comment: Поэтому Вы хотите, чтобы за Вас ее решил кто-то другой?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку каждая игра приводит к выбыванию одного участника, то решение очень простое - нужно найти сумму количества игр во все дни и добавить единицу.

```
infile = open("d:\input.txt", "r")
l = infile.readline()
l = infile.readline()
print(1 + sum([int(s) for s in l.split()]))
infile.close()

при использовании файла
3
2 2 1
выдаёт 6
```

Возможно, подразумевается стандартный ввод, тогда второй `input()` содержит строку с числами

Comment: В том то и дело, я не совсем понимаю, как нужно найти сумму количества игр во все дни. Спасибо заранее (я просто новичок, хочу понять как это делать)